# Setting expectation on NSMutableAttributedString

Tags: ios, unit-testing, nsmutablestring

I am writing a unit test for an "if" statement in a method which returns a NSMutableAttributedString and I am getting some error.

***Actual code for IF statement:***

```
if (conditionIsTrue)
    {
        return [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:NSLocalizedStringWithDefaultValue(@"ABC", 
                                                                                                   @"ABCLibrary", 
                                                                                                   [NSBundle bundleWithName:@"ABCLibraryResources"],
                                                                                                   @"No ABC", 
                                                                                                   @"No ABC String") 
                                                      attributes:[self methodA]];
    }
```

***Unit Test:***

```
ControllerA *controller = [[ControllerA alloc] init];
id mockController = [OCMockObject partialMockForObject:controller];

NSMutableAttributedString *temp = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:NSLocalizedStringWithDefaultValue(@"ABC", 
                                                                                                   @"ABCLibrary", 
                                                                                                   [NSBundle bundleWithName:@"ABCLibraryResources"],
                                                                                                   @"No ABC", 
                                                                                                   @"No ABC String") 
                                                      attributes:[self methodA]];

    [[mockController expect] temp];
```

***Error:***

```
No known instance method for selector temp.
```

Am I setting the expect incorrectly? How can I set an expect for the NSMutableAttributedString?

Answer (score 1):

```
[[mockController expect] temp]
```

tells the mockController to expect that the method temp should be called. temp, here, is just a variable. What you really want is

```
[[[mockController expect] andReturn:temp ] theMethodThatYouHaveTheIfStatementIn]
```